# how to remove class of a div without knowning id of div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi i have a dynamic generated div's list with unique id's for every generated div's,

when click on one of the dynamic generated div this will change the selected div background color by this code `$(this).addClass('add_color');` if again i click on another one div then the older selected div background color should change to default so i tried  this code `$(".add_color").removeClass(".add_color");` but it's not working, please help.

Comment: you should be sharing relevant code, what needs to be done and what you have tried.

Comment: jquery uses events, so the question is when you need to delete them?

Comment: @AshokSri, do use some preffix/suffix for id e.g. foo1, foo2 etc?

Comment: You can specify a separate attribute, say `indicator="Y"` for the generated `div`s and then while removing the classes, you can do:
`$("div[indicator='Y']").removeClass("your_class")`

Comment: hi all, i've edited my question please understand the situation now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify the click handler to add/remove class on click of divs:

```
$('body').on('click','.somedivs',function(){
   $(".add_color").not($(this)).removeClass("add_color");
   $(this).addClass('add_color');
});
```

Comment: @Milind: removeClass(".add_color") should not have a " . " infront of the class name..it should be removeClass("add_color");

Comment: @Milind Anantwar, yeah it's working great ,thank u both  Milind &  Arshad

Answer (score 5):

```
$(".className").removeClass("className")
```

Answer (score 2):

if you just need to remove the class for any div containing that particular class

```
$("div").removeClass('someClass');
```

Comment: @SatyamSaxena you are wrong unfortunately. This would remove the class from all divs.

Comment: @SatyamSaxena: you please undo your downvote and know your mistake

Comment: @SatyamSexana: undo you downvote dear :) you only removed your comment

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".your_class").removeClass("your_class");
```